# Calling methods of NSMutableSet in another function throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: memory-management, exc-bad-access, nsmutableset

I'm stuck on such code:

```
static NSMutableSet* test_set;

-(void)foo1
{
  test_set=[NSMutableSet setWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
  NSLog(@"count:%d",[test_set count]);
}


-(void)foo2
{
  NSLog(@"pointer:%p",test_set);
  NSLog(@"count:%d",[test_set count]); // here I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS
}
```

I calling foo2 only after foo1.
My debug out is like:

```
count:1
pointer:0x262790
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
```

What's wrong?
__
Intresting note: it fails only when foo2 is calling in schedule.__ Sorry, I missed details. Both works perfect. Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re not taking ownership of the object being assigned to `test_set`, which means that it might be deallocated before `-foo2` is sent. In general, if you need an object to survive after the execution of a method then you should take ownership of it — for example, via `+alloc` or `-retain`:

```
-(void)foo1
{
  test_set=[[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], nil];
  NSLog(@"count:%d",[test_set count]);
}
```

or

```
-(void)foo1
{
  test_set=[[NSMutableSet setWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]] retain];
  NSLog(@"count:%d",[test_set count]);
}
```

The rules of taking and relinquishing ownership of objects are discussed in the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

Comment: I supposed that it deallocating after foo1. So I used alloc but getting: `-[__NSPlaceholderSet setWithObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x228560`retain works perfect. Thank you. My bad about forgetting about memory management

Comment: @Morskoy That’s because `+setWithObject:` is a class method, so you can’t send it to the instance returned by `+alloc`. That’s the reason why I’ve used `-initWithObjects:` in the first example, the one that uses `+alloc`.

Comment: @Morskoy Alternatively, you can use the second example — it’s very similar to your original code, with an extra `-retain`.

Comment: @Morskoy Just one further note: if you send `-foo1` more than once, you need to relinquish ownership (release) the previous mutable set stored in that variable. Bear that in mind.

Comment: I understand. I just thinked, that +setWithObject works like new method in C++, and it returns pointer. how pointer can be auto released?! )) only smart pointer I guess.

Comment: @Morskoy It’s similar to smart pointers. When a method returns an object that’s not owned by the caller, the object may be deallocated eventually. That’s the case of `+setWithObject:`, and the case of methods that return autoreleased objects. That page linked in my answer describes how memory management works.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't retained test_set.  The set returned by `setWithObject:` will be autoreleased. If you add

```
[test_set retain];
```

after getting the set back from `setWithObject:` in `foo1()`, and add

```
[test_set release];
```

to the end of `foo2()`, it should work.

You should probably read the Cocoa [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

Comment: Bavarious's answer is a bit clearer, but I'll leave this here because of the link to the Memory Management guide.